# @ngrx/router-store vs @angular/router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

What are the benefits and disadvantages of using [@ngrx/router-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store) instead of [@angular/router](https://angular.io/api/router)?

Comment: Angular2 router and router-deprecated are a bit in a limbo currently. It's unclear in what direction the Angular team will move forward. router-deprecated is uh, deprecated ;-) and router is incomplete and unclear if development will be continued. The ngrx seems quite powerful and feature complete. I don't know if it will work with Angulars offline compiler. The Angular team will hopefully provide more information soon.

Comment: The new `RC.3` uses some concepts from the ngrx router and therefore became more similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a comparison to the now deprecated beta router https://gitter.im/ngrx/store?at=5710e4fc5cd40114649b9399

> the main differences between the component router and ngrx/router are the decisions behind the design. The component router takes a more internal approach when it comes to components if you look at the lifecycle hooks. Our router doesn’t require that the router hook into your components so any component is routable. Another difference is the use of observables. The component router uses promises to handle its lifecycle, whereas ours uses observables because they lend themselves to more of a reactive approach. Our route/query parameters are observable which makes reusing components when parameters change easier. Our router has more streams available for you to subscribe to and react upon. The overall idea is that the browser URL itself is a stream and we are turning that stream into a view of rendered routes. Both routers have a concept of lazy loading, protecting routes, resolving data and lifecycle events. Both still have gaps that need to be filled. If you prefer a more observable approach, our router works very nicely with that.

The new angular2 router will be alot closer to what ngrx/router is today, so if you are using the deprecated beta router now, stay on that until the new router is released and then migrate. If you were starting from nothing, I'd say use ngrx/router because it provides a relatively easy migration path to the new router once its ready.